# Convert and String(path of image) to a Bitmap obj

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

The solution should be straight forward but I cannot find it, my problem it's that I'm reading a xml, and one of the properties inside the xml it's a Bitmap path(string), when I`m reading this xml I would like to convert this string to a Bitmap Obj so I can use through my MXMLs.

Some suggestion?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load the bitmapData like heartcode wrote in their answer.

But to retreive the BitmapData in the loaded function I would do this

```
var ldr:Loader = event.currentTarget as Loader;    
var bitmap:Bitmap = Bitmap(ldr.content);
var bd:BitmapData = new Bitmap(bitmap.bitmapData.clone(), "auto", true);
ldr.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addBitmap);
ldr = null; //Allow flex to gc the Loaded as you now have two copies of the bytes in memory
```

Using the draw method, I think the loader will need to be on the stage so it can be rendered. This will avoid that. You can the assign bd as the source of the BitmapImage

Comment: I`m tried but I`m getting this error now:             ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
 at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
 at flash.display::BitmapData()
 at spark.primitives::BitmapImage/set source()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\primitives\BitmapImage.as:230]
 at mx.binding::Binding/defaultDestFunc()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\binding\Binding.as:270]
 at Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::call()
 at mx.binding::Binding/innerExecute()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\binding\Binding.as:475]

Comment: SWFLoader is a mx control. I think the BitmapImage from spark expects a BitmapData object as the source. Will update my answer with a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

if you need the bitmapdata or the bitmap, try this:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.*;

var bitmapPath:String = "imageFilePath";
var myBitmap:Bitmap;
var bitmapLoader:Loader;

bitmapLoader = new Loader();
bitmapLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, addBitmap);
bitmapLoader.load(new URLRequest(bitmapPath));

function addBitmap(event:Event):void
{
    var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(event.currentTarget.content.width, event.currentTarget.content.height);
    bd.draw(event.currentTarget.content);

    myBitmap = new Bitmap(bd);
    addChild(myBitmap);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MXML, you should just be able to pass the string directly to the "source" attribute of the  tag. Flex abstracts away all of the loading stuff.

Comment: but the I want to pre-load all the images before my app starts!

Comment: That may not necessarily be the best plan - depending on what you're doing, you might consider letting Flex's item renderers load the images for you as needed, it reeeeally makes things easier. Still, if you want to preload everything you might consider using something like LoaderMax - google it, that should help you out!

Answer (score 0):

I posted some code that may help for a similar question that was asked a little while ago. It will take your XML contents and preload the images into an ArrayCollection to use later.

[Embeding images in an Flex application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503923/embeding-images-in-an-flex-application/4504096#4504096)