# Embed image in list

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I am having a list which is rendered to display images , name of all images is in dataprovider of list. Now i am unable to find how to make all images as embedded images as the name is coming from dataprovider?

Below is list:

```
    <s:List itemRenderer="imglist">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>img1.jpg</fx:String>
                <fx:String>img2.jpg</fx:String>
                <fx:String>img3.jpg</fx:String>
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  something like that: http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/09/29/displaying-images-in-a-spark-list-control-using-a-custom-item-renderer-in-flex-4/

2 minutes search in google :)

Of coure you don't have to create custom itemrenderer, instead try this solution:
http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/09/18/displaying-images-in-a-spark-list-control-in-flex-4/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the list of images in your dataprovider and import them into your application. I provided a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503923/embeding-images-in-an-flex-application/4504096#4504096).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <s:List itemRenderer="imglist" dataField="src">
        <s:dataProvider>
            <s:ArrayList>
                <fx:Object src="@Embed('img1.jpg')" />
                <fx:Object src="@Embed('img2.jpg')" />
                <fx:Object src="@Embed('img3.jpg')" />
            </s:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:List>
```

Maybe it will give you some new idea ;)